# SQL (COUNT(*) / locations.area)

Tags: sql

We are learning SQL at school, and my professor has this sql code in his documents.

```
SELECT wp.city, (COUNT(*) / locations.area) AS population_density
FROM world_poulation AS wp 
INNER JOIN location
ON wp.city = locations.city
WHERE locations.state = “Hessen”
GROUP BY wp.city, locations.area
```

Everything is almost clear for me, just the aggregate function with /locations.area doesn't make any sense to me. Can anybody help?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What doesn't make sense?  Two numbers are being divided by each other?

Answer (score 0):

Look at what the query is grouped on, that tells you what each group consists of. In this case, each group is a city, and contains all the rows that have the same value for `wp.city` (and as the `location` table is joined on that value too, the `locations.area` is only included in the grouping so that it can be used in the result).

So each group has a number of rows, and the `COUNT(*)` aggregate will contain the number of rows for each group. The value of `(COUNT(*) / locations.area)` will be the number of rows in the group divided by the value of `locations.area` for that group.

If you would have data like this:

```
world_population
name      city
--------- ---------
John      London
Peter     London
Sarah     London
Malcolm   London
Ian       Cardiff
Johanna   Stockholm
Sven      Stockholm
Egil      Stockholm

locations
city        state          area
----------- -------------- ---------
London      Hessen         2
Cardiff     Somehere else  14
Stockholm   Hessen         1
```

Then you would get a result with two groups (as Cardiff is not in the state Hessen). One group has four people from London which has the area 2, so the population density would be 2. The other group has three people from Stockholm which has the area 1, so the population density would be 3.

---

Side note: There is a typo in the query, as it joins in the table `location` but refers to it as `locations` everywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Try writing it like:

```
SELECT wp.city,
locations.area,
COUNT(*) AS population,
(COUNT(*) / locations.area) AS population_density
FROM world_poulation AS wp
INNER JOIN location
ON wp.city = locations.city
WHERE locations.state = “Hessen”
GROUP BY wp.city, locations.area
```

The key is the GROUP BY statement. You are showing pairs of cities and areas. The COUNT(*) is the number of times a given pair shows up in the table you created by joining world population and location. The area is just a number, so you can divide the area by the COUNT.